# jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using a modal dialog (provided by jQuery UI). Now on the dialog box there are input text boxes with class date. I want to bind Datepicker with these inputs. I've written

```
`$(".date").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            showOn: 'button',
            yearRange: '1970:2015',
            buttonImage: '../../Content/calendar.gif', 
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
```

in ready function. The problem is datepicker is opening in the disabled page behind the modal dialog. How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried z-index or rearranging your DOM?